# Jenkins Configuration Post Build Action

Tags: java, jenkins

I have an archive folder where I put latest changes every day .

I currently, have a post-build action in Jenkins to get the files from a network location. But, I want to get the latest changes from the folder by using a `timestamp`.

Example :

I have Test archive folder, and it contains `test1`, `test 2` and `tests 3` so on every day it increases. Jenkins should basically use the newly created folder `testX`.

Answer (score 1):

if the directory is in the format `test26-02-18` then you can use the `Execute Shell Script` as a post-build action.

when referencing the directory you could use

```
test`date '+%d-%m-%y'`
```